# PostgreSQL: copy to xml without \n

Tags: xml, file, postgresql, copy, postgresql-9.1

I want to write results from queries into xml files.
As I read in the documentation postgres supports only text, csv and binaries. So I use the standard text for my file.

The problem is that postgres puts me automatically after each line / xml element a "\n".
How do prevent this?

This is my copy procedure:

```
copy (SELECT query_to_xml ('SELECT * FROM "Patient" LIMIT 10', TRUE, FALSE, '')) TO '/tmp/lala.xml';
```